# Selecting & Coping a filtered range with an empty cell in column 1

Tags: vba, excel

This code seems to paste the data on row 11 of sheet HAA, just need to append on sheet HAA

```
Sub Run()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long
Dim rf As Range, wsTo As Worksheet, wx As Range

Set rf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").UsedRange
Set wsTo = Sheets("HAA")
Set wx = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAA").UsedRange

x = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

rf.AutoFilter
rf.AutoFilter 12, "associated"
rf.Copy

wsTo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

rf.AutoFilter
rf.AutoFilter 12, "not found"
rf.Offset(1, 0).Copy
```

'I changed this to .select to see what is selected
originally it was .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

```
wsTo.Range("A1" & x).Select 

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(rx, cx).Select` is only selecting one cell and then you copy it.  Are you looking to copy a range of cells?  Entire row(s) of data?

Comment: When you Record Macro after the filtering select `A1` then press Ctrl + Shift + Down and then copy

Comment: I wish I could just use the Ctl-Shift + Down. Unfortunately the first column has a blank. I want to capture the entire range.

Comment: CRUTER, I'm trying to select the entire range to be copied. I have identified the Last Row and Last Column of the filtered range but I need it to slect the entire range. I can't use the Ctl-Shift + down because there is a empty cell in column 1. I could have it ctl-Shift + down twice but the first Column may or may not have an empty cell. Entire Range of cells @CRUTER Maybe I'm thinking about this entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then maybe something like this:

```
Sub Run()
    Dim rangeFrom As Range, wsTo As Worksheet
    Set rangeFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").UsedRange
    Set wsTo = Sheets("HAA")
    wsTo.Columns("A").Insert xlToRight, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove ' insert the column before the paste?

    rangeFrom.AutoFilter
    rangeFrom.AutoFilter 12, "associated"
    rangeFrom.Columns("A").Copy

    wsTo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    rangeFrom.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

to paste after the last row:

```
Dim rangeTo As Range
Set rangeTo = wsTo.UsedRange ' or = wsTo.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rangeTo = rangeTo.Offset(rangeTo.Rows.Count)(1) ' (1) is to get the first cell 
Application.Goto rangeTo ' optional if you want to see where the values will be pasted
rangeTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: It runs but nothing actually happens. However, I am able to step through the entire code and it functions as intended! Any ideas on this? Excel 2007 as well.

Comment: In Design Mode, right-click the button and `Assign Macro...` or `View Code`. If you can run it from `View` tab > `Macros` then the problem is in your button. Also, SO Documentation has some good topics http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201609151805447964206

Comment: Thank you for your help Slai! You opened my eyes as well.

Comment: Slai, I have another issue, I'm attempting to append another filtered range into the same sheet as before and it only pastes roughly half way.

rf.AutoFilter
rf.AutoFilter 12, "not found"
rf.Offset(1, 0).Copy
        
 wsTo.Range("A1" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: @FonR you can post a new question with the code that you use and maybe a screenshot or description of the problem, and I'll look at it